# How small font sizes and details can I print in a risograph?

Tags: print-design, risograph

How small font sizes and details can I print in a [risograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risograph)?

Does it matter which model of riso machine it is?

How much difference does the coarseness of the paper do?

(A print test scanned with scale would be wonderful, if anyone has a link to that it would save my day! :) )

Comment: won't this depend on the model and the year of manufacture?

Comment: @Yorik You might be right, added this to the question.

Comment: It'd depend on the particular risograph (they have different DPIs) and the particular typeface.

Comment: When I google for Risograph and dpi, 300 to 600 dpi seems to be common.